# how to get the value of the 4th or 5th child of an element using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I use this XML source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="simulation-request.xsd">
<set>
    <hP />
    <para>
        <setP>
            <nom1>acc</nom1>
            <nom2></nom2>
            <typ>T</typ>
            <oP>T_EQUALS</oP>
            <val1>40</val1>
            <bId>21</bId>
        </setP>
    </para>
    <issuers />
</set>
<set>
    <hP>
        <sethP>
            <hTyp>EX</hTyp>             
            <tFt>L_D</tFt>
            <tFv>1</tFv>
            <sCF>cd</sCF>
            <setP>
                <nom1>bount</nom1>
                <oP>NLO</oP>
                <val1>00</val1>
                <bId>22</bId>
            </setP>
            <setP>
                <nom1>bount</nom1>
                <oP>NLO</oP>
                <val1>00</val1>
                <bId>23</bId>
            </setP>
            <setP>
                <nom1>bount</nom1>
                <oP>NLO</oP>
                <val1>00</val1>
                <bId>31</bId>
            </setP>

        </sethP>
    </hP>
    <para>
        <setP>
            <nom1>bount</nom1>
            <nom2></nom2>
            <typ>LO</typ>
            <oP>T_C</oP>
            <val1>1</val1>
            <bId>24</bId>
        </setP>
    </para>
    <issuers />
</set>  
</sets>
```

with this XSLT source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"   xml:space="preserve"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>   
    <xsl:for-each select="sets/set/hP | sets/set/para/setP">            
            <com-set-cond b.name="netInternalMs" name="{.//bId}">
            </com-set-cond><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

and the output is looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<com-set-cond b.name="netInternalMs" name=""/>
<com-set-cond b.name="netInternalMs" name="21"/>
<com-set-cond b.name="netInternalMs" name="22"/>
<com-set-cond b.name="netInternalMs" name="24"/>
```

but the expected output have to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<com-set-cond b.name="netInternalMs" name="21"/>
<com-set-cond b.name="netInternalMs" name="22"/>
<com-set-cond b.name="netInternalMs" name="23"/>
<com-set-cond b.name="netInternalMs" name="31"/>
<com-set-cond b.name="netInternalMs" name="24"/>
```

where each number of 21,22,23,31 and 24 are the values of the element **bId** in the whole xml file and when ther is no **bId** element in an ancestor like the first tag , my transformation will not display anything and not a line with an empty value for "name" as the first line in the output file after using my transformation
Does anyone know, how to do this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your **xsl:for-each**

```
<xsl:for-each select="sets/set/hP | sets/set/para/setP">
```

In particular, the **sets/set/hP** xpath. This will match two **hP** elements. The first is empty, and so you get the empty **name** attribute generated. The second contains three **setP** elements, but doing `name="{.//bId}"` will only pick up the first (bId = 22 in this case)

So, you may want to change your **xsl:for-each** to this

```
<xsl:for-each select="sets/set/hP/sethP/setP | sets/set/para/setP">
```

If you are not worried about what level your **setP** elements occur, you could simplify this to the following

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//setP">
```

Do note, it is often preferred to use **xsl:apply-templates** over **xsl:for-each** as this can make code more readable, reduce indentation, and is easier to re-use code.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>    
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//setP" /> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="setP">
   <com-set-cond b.name="netInternalMs" name="{.//bId}" />
   <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>  
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Tim, I get now the expected output and I use the example with the "apply-templates". Thanks a lot. Franky